Strange plug socket wiring – help please


Two brown (live?) going into ground.
Two black (also live?) going into live.
Two blue (neutral) correctly going to neutral.

Did someone use ground to create a loop for the live?
I'm fitting a new socket – I'm assuming I shouldn't copy whatever logic this person used. There's no ground wire in this room and I'm in europe.
Please let me know if there's a simple solution here, or I'll call the electrician.

Did you test those live wires? if not or you don't have test equipment get an electrician. I would test and then make sure only earth or ground wires go to the earth terminal ' usually shown with green/yellow stripped wire.

While wire colours are usually standardized to a location, you do not assume they are being used as they should be.  People do weird stuff.
